# "lateinit property mediaRecorder has not been initialized" in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, video-capture, android-camera2

I'm trying to build a simple recording app in Kotlin, but I'm having a lot of trouble when getting an error "lateinit property mediaRecorder has not been initialized".

I suspect this is because I am not constructing the mediaRecorder object with a context (constructing without context has been deprecated), but I am not sure if this theory is right, because I am not sure how to even obtain the context to pass in.

lateinit property mediaRecorder has not been initialized

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_view)
        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager


        findViewById<Button>(R.id.record_button).apply {
            setOnClickListener {
                if (isRecording) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop()
                    mediaRecorder.reset()
                } else {
                    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
                    setupMediaRecorder()
                    startRecording()
                }

                isRecording = !isRecording
            }
        }
```

I've tried playing around with the MediaRecorder class, but I am honestly just very lost at how to solve this issue.

```
    private lateinit var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
    private var isRecording: Boolean = false

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ncontext = this

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_view)
        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager


        findViewById<Button>(R.id.record_button).apply {
            setOnClickListener {
                if (isRecording && ::mediaRecorder.isInitialized) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop()
                    mediaRecorder.reset()
                } else {
                    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
                    setupMediaRecorder()
                    startRecording()
                }

                isRecording = !isRecording
            }
        }

        if (!wasCameraPermissionWasGiven()) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_REQUEST_RESULT)
        }
        startBackgroundThread()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startBackgroundThread()
        if (textureView.isAvailable && shouldProceedWithOnResume) {
            setupCamera()
        } else if (!textureView.isAvailable){
            textureView.surfaceTextureListener = surfaceTextureListener
        }
        shouldProceedWithOnResume = !shouldProceedWithOnResume
    }

    private fun setupCamera() {
        val cameraIds: Array<String> = cameraManager.cameraIdList

        for (id in cameraIds) {
            val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id)

            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue
            }

            val streamConfigurationMap : StreamConfigurationMap? = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)

            if (streamConfigurationMap != null) {
                previewSize = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG).maxByOrNull { it.height * it.width }!!
                videoSize = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder::class.java).maxByOrNull { it.height * it.width }!!
                imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(previewSize.width, previewSize.height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler)
            }
            cameraId = id
        }
    }

    private fun wasCameraPermissionWasGiven() : Boolean {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            surfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(textureView.surfaceTexture!!, textureView.width, textureView.height)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Camera permission is needed to run this application",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            )
                .show()
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                )) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                intent.data = Uri.fromParts("package", this.packageName, null)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun connectCamera() {
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraStateCallback, backgroundHandler)
    }

    private fun setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(createFile().absolutePath)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10_000_000)
        mediaRecorder.prepare()
    }

    private fun startRecording() {
        val surfaceTexture : SurfaceTexture? = textureView.surfaceTexture
        surfaceTexture?.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)

        val previewSurface: Surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        val recordingSurface = mediaRecorder.surface
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordingSurface)

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(previewSurface, recordingSurface), captureStateVideoCallback, backgroundHandler)
    }

    /**
     * Surface Texture Listener
     */

    private val surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(texture: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
            if (wasCameraPermissionWasGiven()) {
                setupCamera()
                connectCamera()
            }
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(texture: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {

        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(texture: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(texture: SurfaceTexture) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: It gets initiated here:

Comment: Why is *"lateinit property mediaRecorder has not been initialized"* repeated? Is it intentional?

Comment: Can you share the crash log.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `mediaRecorder` initial by `::mediaRecorder.isInitialized`
. Add it to the condition statement:

```
if (isRecording && ::mediaRecorder.isInitialized) {
   mediaRecorder.stop()
   mediaRecorder.reset()
} else {
   mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
   setupMediaRecorder()
   startRecording()
}
```

Comment: I added it to the check and I believe that it worked though I now get a "lateinit property videoSize has not been initialized". Would applying a similar check for videoSize be the best move?

Comment: @Akigomon505 i think you can. But you should init all your values carefully to make sure they work correctly.

Comment: I have videoSize intiated as `videoSize = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder::class.java).maxByOrNull { it.height * it.width }!!` but for some reason it isn't being initialized, not sure how to check to fix it

Comment: @Akigomon505 it depends on how did you init and use it so please provide more detail

Comment: I just updated my original post to add more code. I believe that videoSize is initialized but the application crashes when I try to access the size value `mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.width, videoSize.height)`

Comment: @Akigomon505 app crashes because your `videoSize` has not been initialized at `mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.width, videoSize.height)` line. This is because you call that line in `onCreate` which is executed before `onResume` where was you call `setupCamera()` function to init the `videoSize`. So to solve this you need to call `setupCamera()` before `setupMediaRecorder()`. Or you can try to check `::videoSize.isInitialized` on the condition too. Let me know it it work

Comment: That worked! Thank you for all your help. Though now my cameraDevice is the one not being intialized.